# ¿Cómo posicionar un boton del lado derecho del header?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Estoy queriendo ubicar mi botón de cerrar sesión en el header y del lado derecho, pero por mas que intento y pongo y saco clases de Bootstrap 5 no estoy pudiendo lograr esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi está ubicado el boton actualmente y marqué en dónde quiero que esté.

Y éste es mi codigo en html:

```
<header class="bg-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="navbar-header p-2">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="~/Home/Login">Cerrar Sesión</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Alguna ayuda o consejo? Ya intenté con `position-absolute` pero ésto me lo saca de mi franja negra, `end-0` o `me-0` tampoco funcionaron, me lo dejaban del lado izquierdo.

Si uso los 3 juntos funciona pero me lo saca de la franja negra.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega al div que contiene el botón:

```
style ="display:flex; justify-content:flex-end"
```

Ejemplo:

```html
<header class="bg-dark border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
    <div class="navbar-header p-2" style ="display: flex; justify-content:flex-end">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="~/Home/Login">Cerrar Sesión</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: También se pueden utilizar las clases `d-flex justify-content-end` que [provee Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/).

Answer (score 0):

veo que haces uso de bootstrap

te dejo un ejemplo de lo que parece quieres hacer publicado en el siguiente link de la w3schools
[navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_form&stacked=h)

igual te dejo el código del ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mynavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <h3>Navbar Forms</h3>
  <p>You can also include forms inside the navigation bar.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Genial gracias! voy a pegarle una revisada a la documentación!